# `to` function for a number in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What does `to` function do in:

```
rdd.flatMap(x => x.to(3))
```

?

`rdd` is composed of `{1, 2, 3, 3}` and the above function returns `{1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3}`
I have been googling "scala number to function" and its variants, but can't seem to find what it does.

Comment: `x.to(3)` produces the range of numbers between `x` and `3`. E.g. `1.to(3)` is `1, 2, 3`, `2.to(3)` is `2, 3`, and `3.to(3)` is `3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> To function

To create a `Range` in Scala, use the predefined methods `to` and `by`.

Example:

`1 to 3` will give  `Range(1, 2, 3)`

> What does to function do in RDD

a) **Looking into map function**:

```
sc.range(1L, 6L).map(x => x to 3).collect.foreach(println)
```

This prints

```
NumericRange(1, 2, 3)
NumericRange(2, 3)
NumericRange(3)
NumericRange() // 4 to 3 returns an empty Range
NumericRange() // 5 to 3 returns an empty Range
```

b) **Looking into flatMap function**:

```
sc.range(1L, 6L).flatMap(x => x to 3).collect.foreach(println)
```

This prints

```
1
2
3
2
3
3
```

It combines *mapping* and *flattening*. flatMap takes a function that works on the nested lists and then concatenates the results back together.

An important thing to understand about flatMap is that anything that looks like an *`empty array will disappear`*. so `NumericRange()` doesn't appears in `flatMap` result .

Answer (score 0):

rdd.flatMap(x => x.to(3)) works as follows:

```
1. rdd.map(x => x.to(3))
   a) fetch the first element of {1, 2, 3, 3}, that is 1
   b) apply to x => x.to(3), that is 1.to(3), 
      that is also explained as 1 to   3, it will generate the range {1, 2, 3}
   c) fetch the second element of {1, 2, 3, 3}, that is 2
   d) apply to x => x.to(3), that is 2.to(3), that is also explained as 2 to 3,
      it will generate the range {2, 3}
   e) repeat above, 3 to 3 will get {3}, the final 3 will get {3}
   f) so finally, you get {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {3}, {3}}

2. flatMap is combination of map and flattern
   so flatmap will make {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {3}, {3}} become {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3}
```

So, x.to(y) just to generate a range, [x, y], you can use repl to verify it.

```
C:\Windows\System32>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_55).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> 2 to 5
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(2, 3, 4, 5)
```